# why i have some missing files when cmake generate build folder ? (Maya 2020 - CMake 3.16.4 - VS 2017)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, maya, maya-api

I exactly followed the instruction in API help to create visual studio project:
[The CMakeLists.txt File guide](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2020/ENU/?guid=Maya_SDK_MERGED_Building_Your_Own_Plugin_The_CMakeList_File_html)

but I got this error:

```
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
  contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
  code such as

    project(ProjectName)

  near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().

  CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
  line.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

by the way , this error didn't stop the process and CMake generate the build folder for me
but as you can see it didn't create some files i think , there are no helloworld.vcxproj & helloworld.vcxproj.filters

[image: Missing Files]

FYI : i use Cmake 3.16.4 and visual studio 2017

Comment: Please, show **complete** output of CMake. At the end of that output should be a line, which tells whether the configuration is completed or failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial is incomplete, as it is missing the [`project()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html) command. Your CMake project should **always** have at least one `project()` command, as it is used to initialize some pretty essential variables, and the language used in the CMake file, among other things. From the CMake documentation:

> The top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file for a project must contain a literal, direct call to the `project()` command; loading one through the `include()` command is not sufficient. If no such call exists, CMake will issue a warning and pretend there is a `project(Project)` at the top to enable the default languages (`C` and `CXX`).

Using the `set()` command to initialize `PROJECT_NAME` is bad practice, as the `project()` call *also* does this for you. I would suggest modifying the CMake file to include the `project()` command instead:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

include($ENV{DEVKIT_LOCATION}/cmake/pluginEntry.cmake)

# Set the project here.
project(exampleNode)

set(RESOURCES_FILES myResource.xpm)

set(MEL_FILES 
     exampleNode.mel)

set(SOURCE_FILES
     exampleNode.cpp
     ${MEL_FILES}
)

set(LIBRARIES
    OpenMaya Foundation
)

find_package(MtoA)
find_alembic()
build_plugin()
```

Comment: @AminKhormaei You can try removing your build folder, and running CMake *from scratch*, which will guarantee that the old CMake cache is removed.

Comment: I did that too ,

Comment: @AminKhormaei The message in your question post is not an error, it is a **warning**. It does not indicate whether or not CMake completely successfully, so as requested by Tsyvarev, please provide the **full** CMake output in your question post. It would also be helpful to provide the code in `pluginEntry.cmake` to better understand what might be going wrong.

Comment: i added project() after minimum requirement and solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(test)

set(PROJECT_NAME test)


include($ENV{DEVKIT_LOCATION}/cmake/pluginEntry.cmake)



set(RESOURCES_FILES myResource.xpm)

set(MEL_FILES 
    test.mel)

set(SOURCE_FILES
        test.cpp
        ${MEL_FILES}
    )

set(LIBRARIES
    OpenMaya Foundation
    )

build_plugin()
```

Comment: The syntax here is incorrect. Using `project()` without a project name will generate a CMake error.