# project (PROJECT) called with incorrect number of arguments [CMake] [MAYA 2020]

Tags: c++, api, cmake, sdk, maya

as you can see my CMakeLists.txt content is :
I should add this that my MAYA version is 2020 but my devkit is 2020 hotfix 1
could it be the problem?

I don't know why the Autodesk documentation or other companies are not complete.
they just explain things generally not in detail

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project()

set(PROJECT_NAME test)


include($ENV{DEVKIT_LOCATION}/cmake/pluginEntry.cmake)



set(RESOURCES_FILES myResource.xpm)

set(MEL_FILES 
    test.mel)

set(SOURCE_FILES
        test.cpp
        ${MEL_FILES}
    )

set(LIBRARIES
    OpenMaya Foundation
    )

build_plugin()
```

when I wanna generate in CMake I get these Errors:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  project PROJECT called with incorrect number of arguments


    CMake Warning (dev) at M:/Autodesk_Maya_2020_DEVKIT_Windows_Hotfix_1/devkitBase/cmake/pluginEntry.cmake:204 (add_library):
      ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
      support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
      to problems.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:25 (build_plugin)
    This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

    CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
    Missing variable is:
    CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
    CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
    Missing variable is:
    CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
    CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
    Missing variable is:
    CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES
    CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly.
    Missing variable is:
    CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
    CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
    Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
    Foundation_PATH
        linked by target "test" in directory C:/Users/amink/Desktop/API Project
    OpenMaya_PATH
        linked by target "test" in directory C:/Users/amink/Desktop/API Project
```

Comment: I would expect [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60722686/3440745) to your previous question should explain that `project()` **accepts an argument**. Exactly this is written in the error message `project PROJECT called with incorrect number of arguments`. What else is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

project() shouldn't be empty project(test) solved my problem

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
    project(test)

    set(PROJECT_NAME test)


    include($ENV{DEVKIT_LOCATION}/cmake/pluginEntry.cmake)



    set(RESOURCES_FILES myResource.xpm)

    set(MEL_FILES 
        test.mel)

    set(SOURCE_FILES
            test.cpp
            ${MEL_FILES}
        )

    set(LIBRARIES
        OpenMaya Foundation
        )

    build_plugin()
```